# Grid on aligned equations in ConTeXt

Tags: context, grid-typesetting

Grid typesetting works quite well in ConTeXt for single-line equations (see the first example below). However, replacing it by any number of aligned equations (including just a single "aligned" equation) causes the rest of the page not to be aligned with the grid (see the second example below). **Can I get grid typesetting for aligned systems of equations?**

```
\setuplayout
[grid=yes]

\setupindenting[yes,medium]

\definecolumnset[example][n=2]

\setupformulas[indentnext=auto] 

\starttext

\showgrid

\startcolumnset[example]
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\startformula
x^2 + y^2 = z^2
\stopformula
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\stopcolumnset

\stoptext
```

[image]

Replacing the formula by

```
\startformula
\startmathalignment
\NC x^2 + y^2 \NC = z^2\NR[+]
\NC u^2 + v^2 \NC = w^2\NR[+]
\stopmathalignment
\stopformula
```

I get

[image]

Comment: When you add `\setupformulas[align=middle]` to your document the paragraph after the formula will be on the grid but I haven’t tested if there there are side effect (e.g. changed alignment) for other formulas.

Comment: @Metafox, strange, is `align=middle` not the standard setting?

Comment: P.S. Thanks! That sounds so far like the easiest and most "correct" solution.

Comment: The default value is `align=normal`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Nevertheless, I think this can be regarded as a bug.

Comment: You can send a message to the ConTeXt mailing list.

Comment: I'm currently in the process of being approved there, but yes, that is my plan.

Comment: @Metafox Sorry for the many questions, but ConTeXt is really not very well documented: What is the different between `align=middle` and `align=normal` in general?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25778/discussion-between-metafox-and-gaussler).

Comment: @Metafox how are you? to say that by having `\setupformulas[align=middle]` in your document, the paragraphs will be on the grid, is an understatement. Not the most deliberate approach, but anyhow, it's only TeX on a grid I guess, and I already sound nitpicking, put it on the baseline goody two shoe creature :)

Comment: I tried reporting this on the ConTeXt mailing list days ago, but so far they have completely ignored me.

Comment: @Gaussler nah, I don't think they would ignore you. Try again. They usually respond. they're very proactive there. Or wait for an update. I'm disappointed with some of their methods, that is, in the lack of acknowledgment when something is not working, and their refusal to accept it. So If I were you, I'd wait for an update. :)

Comment: You're right, finally got in touch with Hagen himself. It appears there will be a fix in an upcoming beta.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to wrap your formula into a pair of `startlinecorrection ... stoplinecorrection`; this will disregard the grid for the formulas themselves but align the material after them on the grid, which I assume is what you want. If you need more control, have a look at chapter 4 of *It's in the Details*, available at the [pragma website]: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFKPr.png)

[image]

Comment: I looked in Details already, but there is a striking lack of coverage of multiline equations.

Comment: I shall accept your answer if no one can provide me with the ideal solution, the equations themselves being placed on the grid. It would seem that ConTeXt has no support for that at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this was a bug.  In TeXlive 2017 your MWE is working just fine.

```
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\setupindenting[yes,medium]

\definecolumnset[example][n=2]

\setupformulas[indentnext=auto] 

\starttext

\showgrid

\startcolumnset[example]
  \input knuth
  \input knuth
  \input knuth
  \startformula
    \startmathalignment
      \NC x^2 + y^2 \NC = z^2\NR[+]
      \NC u^2 + v^2 \NC = w^2\NR[+]
    \stopmathalignment
  \stopformula
  \input knuth
\stopcolumnset

\stoptext
```

[image]

If you are using the **latest beta** and you want to number these aligned formulas, use

```
\placeformula
\startformula
  \startmathalignment[number=auto,grid=both]
    \NC x^2 + y^2 \NC = z^2\NR
    \NC u^2 + v^2 \NC = w^2\NR
  \stopmathalignment
\stopformula
```

Comment: It is nice to see that you get back to the grid again! With your code, in the latest beta, there is an extra line after the aligned formulas. This means that the code after starts on line 22, and the formula is not aligned vertically in my opinion. What do you think?

Comment: @mickep You could add for instance `grid=both`.  The problem with boxes in math mode and gridsnapping is that in math there is no longer a notion of lineheight.  An integral for example generate a *huge* lineheight compared to a letter.  Therefore there does not exist a canonical gridsnapping for all multiline formulas.  You have to choose on each occurrence.  You could also `\setupmathalignment[grid=no]` and hope that it looks fine if the box is just centred between the paragraphs.

Comment: @mickep At some point in the future I want to write my own math integration for ConTeXt, based on `amsmath` and hopefully I find a way to do it right.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The grid=both works fine in the latest beta in this case. This looks promising, and I hope that OP is satisfied. About your plans for some amsmath based math integration, it sounds interesting. It would be good if that was actually in the core, but maybe that clashes with something.